# TextField within SwiftUI List has cursor positioning error when editing Core Data class instance string?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, textfield, swiftui-list

When editing text within a TextField which is in a SwiftUI List there is a cursor positioning error that occurs?  Any ideas how to avoid this?  See video and code attached.

Note - Not sure if this matters however gcTask is a NSManagedObject (i.e. core data class instance).

UPDATE: Now confirmed this issue does directly relate to the case where the TextField string variable is tied to a Core Data class instance string attribute.  In this case the core data NSManagedClass GCTask has a string attribute "title".  That is why does this issue occur with my core data usage, and does not if I just used a local @State string variable?

Background: Wanting to have a simple ToDo list with the ability to click into a row and edit in-line, which you do see in some apps.  Just want to understand how to do this in SwiftUI.

Code:

```
struct GCTaskRow : View {
    @ObservedObject var gcTask: GCTask
    @State var beingEdited : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: gcTask.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.gcTask.completed.toggle()
                GCCoreData.save()
            }

            VStack {
                TextField(
                    "Enter:",
                    text: $gcTask.title,
                    onEditingChanged: { changed in
                        print("\(self.gcTask.title)  => onEditingChanged = \(changed)")
                        self.beingEdited = changed
                    },
                    onCommit: {
                        print("\(self.gcTask.title)  => onCommit")
                        // GCCoreData.save()  // normally save here
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Animated GIF - What happens when I click in TextField and type in 1,2,3,4,5:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following simple test works well for me on ios 13.4.1 and catalyst.
This points to gcTask as the source of the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var gcTask = "xxxx"
@State var beingEdited = false
var body: some View {
    List {
        TextField("Enter:", text: $gcTask,
            onEditingChanged: { changed in
                print("\(self.gcTask)  => onEditingChanged = \(changed)")
                self.beingEdited = changed
        },
            onCommit: {
                print("\(self.gcTask)  => onCommit")
                // where I'll put code to save/finalise update
        }
        )
    }
}
}
```

Comment: tks - let me try - re gcTask (from my Core Data GCTask class), I've put more code for the view in the question - no ideas re what this might trigger the issue (versus a local @State variable)?

Comment: yes confirmed it is specific to my GCTask core data instance attribute.  I'll update the question to be more clear.